# Astyanax. How to read SET and MAP Datatypes in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I am trying to read a column of type Set from cassandra using the following astyanax code.

```
val genres = col.getColumnByName("genres")
val genValue = genres.getValue(new SetSerializer[String](UTF8Type.instance))
```

I found similar code in Astyanax documentation as well

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Collections

but I get error

```
org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Unexpected extraneous bytes after set value
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.SetSerializer.deserialize(SetSerializer.java:64)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.SetSerializer.deserialize(SetSerializer.java:27)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.compose(AbstractType.java:142)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.serializers.SetSerializer.fromByteBuffer(SetSerializer.java:32)
```

My table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE movielens_small.movies (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    avg_rating float,
    genres set<text>,
    name text,
    release_date date,
    url text,
    video_release_date date
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
```

I can easily to a select query in cqlsh. so I don't think there is some problem with db.

Edit:: I also tried

```
val myset = ListType.getInstance(UTF8Type.instance)
val genValue = myset.compose(genres.getByteBufferValue)
```

But it throws the same error that there are unexpected extraneous bytes.

Edit2:: I also tried

```
val genValue = new String(genres.getByteBufferValue.array(), "UTF-8")
```

This doesn't throw an error, and I can see data... but its like gibberish.

[image]

Edit3:: I also tried

```
val setSer = new SetSerializer[String](UTF8Type.instance)
val buf = genres.getByteBufferValue
val genValue = setSer.fromByteBuffer(buf)
println(s"${name.getStringValue} rating: ${avgRating.getFloatValue} genres: ${genValue}")
```

But again the same problem of `org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Unexpected extraneous bytes after set value`

My cassandra table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE movielens_small.movies (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    avg_rating float,
    genres set<text>,
    name text,
    release_date date,
    url text,
    video_release_date date
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: What is the code you have to put the values into the db? What are the cassandra db / library versions?

Comment: I added the table definition to my question. My code is located here https://github.com/abhsrivastava/AstyanaxScala. you can look at my build.sbt file for all libraries and versions.